# Get username of sender from event.message object using telethon

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I can't get the username of the sender of a event.message object when a message arrived in a group.

I tried get_entity, get_input_entity method. But that shows error. 
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'chat'
I don't even know how to deal with coroutine object

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=input_groups_entity))
    async def handler(event):
        print(event)
        sender = event.message.chat_id
        perticipants = client.get_participants(event.message.to_id)
        np = client.get_input_entity(event.message.from_id)
        await client.send_message(event.message.to_id, message=event.message.message)
```

I want to just extract the username from the message object

Comment: maybe `event.message._sender` will give you some info?

Comment: @IvanVinogradov It is just saying None. Means this doesn't exist

Answer (score 13):

To get the full info about the sender you would need to do :

```
sender = await event.get_sender()
print(sender.username)
```

The reason you got that error is that you forgot to put `await` before doing `client.get_input_entity`